# Angular 9 - Quando colo o link absoluto de um link interno do meu site ele dá erro

Tags: angular

Por exemplo:
Link do Portfólio:  http://www.impactodesigner.com.br/portfolio/

Se eu colar no browser já com um link interno ele dá erro, por exemplo:
http://www.impactodesigner.com.br/portfolio/curriculum

Não sei se na hora do build tenho que fazer algo, estou especificando assim:
ng build --base-href http://www.impactodesigner.com.br/portfolio/

E na metatag no "dist/index.html" ele coloca isso (lembrando que é um subdominio):

```html
<base href="http://www.impactodesigner.com.br/portfolio/">
```

Answer (score 0):

As rotas do angular não são reconhecida pelo servidor.

Você precisa configurar corretamente o **web.config** do servidor, abaixo um exemplo para o IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: vc. quis dizer IIS ou ISS, minha hospedagem é Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema com .htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```